# Solr - return field value as JSON

Tags: json, solr

Take for example

```
{'name':'Ruth', 'age':28, 'city':'madrid'}
```

This JSON gets indexed and is stored as a string. Is there a way to return this field value as JSON in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this which did what I want

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1690

Answer (score 1):

Add &wt=json at the end of your query to get Solr to return a response in JSON format.  XML is default. For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*&wt=json
```